# How to pass custom resource in asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am sure this is possible using ConnectionConfiguration, but I am not able to find a documentation for the same. I need a different resource than `Smack`.
My current code looks like this -

```
ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST,PORT, SERVICE);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connectionConfig);
connection.connect();
```

How can I pass a custom JID resource in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to pass the resource in the login method:

```
conn.login(username, password, resource);
```

Reference: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.html#login(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Ah.. I was looking at the wrong place(Configuration instead of login). Anyways thanks a lot for the answer and the documentation link.